# How to determine spring data JPA is executed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to extend JPARepository in spring boot 2.5.3 and h2 database.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
      boolean deleteCustomerById(Long id);
}
```

Returning a boolean because service and controller needs to know if it was successful operation and send appropriate response entity.

```
 public boolean delete(Long id) {
        return customerRepository.deleteCustomerById(id);
    }
```

Controller

```
@DeleteMapping(path = "/customers/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    Optional<Customer> foundCustomer= customerService.findById(id);
    return foundCustomer.map(customer -> {
        if (customerService.delete(id)){
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }else {
            return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build();
        }
    }).orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Doing this way gives an error while testing the repository.

```
@Test
public void deleteCustomerByIdSuccess(){
    boolean result=customerRepository.deleteCustomerById(1L);
    assertTrue(result,"Customer should be deleted successfully");
    Optional<Customer> foundCustomer=customerRepository.findById(1L);
    assertFalse(foundCustomer.isPresent(),"Customer 1 should be deleted and not be found.");
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Boolean are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.deleteCustomerById(Unknown Source)
    at com.prabhakar.customer.repository.CustomerRepositoryTest.deleteCustomerByIdSuccess(CustomerRepositoryTest.java:67)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

But when I change repository to:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
      int deleteCustomerById(Long id);
}
```

And validate with 1 it works.

There is a default deleteById method but it returns void.

```
void deleteById(ID var1);
```

It want it to return a boolean,so I tried to use my own Implementaion as above.

What does Spring data JPA use internally?(Is it executeUpdate?)
I can see the logs, and the SQL queries but how do we come to know if it has been executed or by returning void.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create your own custom `delete` method.
Note that below `CustomerRepository` extends also `CustomCustomerRepository`.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, CustomCustomerRepository {
      
}
```

Create the "custom" repository:

```
public interface CustomCustomerRepository {

    boolean deleteCustomerById(Long id);
}
```

and provide your custom implementation of the delete method in

```
public class CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomCustomerRepository {

        @Override    
        boolean deleteCustomerById(Long id) {
            // your specific code here, 
            // delete the record and return either true or false 
            // depending what you have in mind
        }
}
```

You can also refer here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of `Derived Delete Queries`

You can use several different return types to validate delete operation.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
      Customer deleteById(Long id); // To get deleted record
      Long deleteById(Long id); // To get deleted record count
      void deleteById(Long id); // To get ignore result
}
```

If You want to be sure that the record has been deleted, You have to check the result.

As far as I know, `boolean` type is not supported by `Derived Delete Queries`

However, If the `deleteById` would return a `boolean` you have to check what went wrong if the result is false. This would mean that the entity could not be deleted what would be misleading.

Comment: If I am using ```Long deleteById(Long id);``` // To get deleted record count. This works.
How do i check what went wrong?
It would return a 0 if no rows are affected. I would have to equate with ```1``` or ```0```. Hence my question why not return a boolean instead.